# Saving classes not objects in an array

Tags: c#

```
bool InContext(Class[] array, Item item)
{
  for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++)
   {
     if(item is array[i])
     {
        return true;
     }
   } 
   return false;
}
```

Is there anyway to store a bunch of classes in an array, so that I can tell if one of my items is inheriting from it?

I want this function for checking if an item is within context (for context sensitive menus) to be fairly dynamic. so writing it in manually isn't really an option.

Comment: You can use [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 10):

Use [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of 'Class' in your header line.

Then you can have:

```
bool InContext(Item item, Type[] accepted)
{
  Type itemType = item.GetType();

  return accepted.Any(x=> x.IsAssignableFrom(itemType));
}
```